# Automate Edge/Chrome Web Browser via VBA without Selenium or External Installations

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Currently for my team of 6 people, 5 of which have no programming/development knowledge, we are using a web automation for filling out a web form in Internet Explorer via VBA and Excel macros. The benefit of the current methodology is that no one on my team has to install any external software/packages when running the automation, since it only requires Microsoft Office Excel VBA.

Are there are solutions for utilizing the existing code for either Microsoft Edge or Chrome without having to install additional software/packages?

Comment: Short answer: no, you need an API external to microsoft, this is because the structure has changed, it is like asking to have word functions on wordpad without the need to install office word. A workaroud will be to do clicks and send keys commands, but this is very unreliable. I know the red tapes you get a company, but sadly, the world moves on and IE is a security risk as now.

Comment: I understand, thanks for inputting @Sgdva. I am running into the issue of red tape you mentioned, but I am sure my team and company will understand that we need to adapt and move forward with external APIs to avoid security risks.

Comment: @Sgdva Actually, you can automate Chrome from VBA using WebSockets.  https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Comment: @ExcelHero thanks for chiming in, you're really living up to your name. I was not aware of WebSockets, this is very much appreciated. Other than the link provided are there other resources/documentation more oriented towards VBA and how to utilize?

Comment: It's sparse, but Google can help. Selenium itself is built on WebSockets.

Comment: @ExcelHero It could be, here is a discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/6ctrd9/websocket_in_vba/) about it, however, selenium can be translated to more future solutions easier, like python (at least on my experience using Selenium on python after being used on excel was pretty straight forward).

Comment: @Sgdva Selenium is built on WebSockets.

Comment: @ExcelHero agreed, however, you will likely will need to address for everything that selenium has already adjusted for. Nevertheless, the options are there and it's great that you brought it up to the table so the best solution can be used, thanks :)

Comment: @Sgdva Well, yes. The entire point of Selenium as a library is to simplify WebSocket automation of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This will not directly let you use your existing solution, as the model to control Edge/Chrome is different than the VBA code to control IE, but it is possible to control Edge/Chrome/Firefox from Excel/VBA without additional installed software thanks to their support of the Chrome Developer Protocol via websockets.  For reference, a class the allows connecting to websockets in VBA can be found at https://github.com/EagleAglow/vba-websocket-class and is used for another project that automates Edge/Chrome from Excel using websockets https://github.com/PerditionC/VBAChromeDevProtocol  But if you can use Selenium or Playwright or another tool, it will probably be more reliable.  There is also https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5307593/Automate-Chrome-Edge-using-VBA which is the original basis for above project - it has additional support for saving the connection information so can be used across macro invocation.