# How to count the number of tables in a webpage using Microsoft EDGE

Tags: html, excel, vba, import, microsoft-edge

I'm struggling with Excel data query. I would need to import a specific table from a webpage.
Said table is always the penultimate among the tables contained in the page.
Now the challenge is that depending on the actual webpage, the overall number of tables may change.

So I was thinking to retrieve the number of tables and get the last - 1. Without success so far...

I've tried this (found by Googling) without success:

```
Sub Count_Tables_on_a_Webpage()
    Dim Edge As Object
    Set Edge = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Edge.ShellExecute "microsoft-edge:https://https://www.fidal.it/atleta/Elia-Ghezzi/fbORkpOicWo%3D"

    Dim StartTime As Double
    StartTime = Timer

    Do While Edge.Windows.Count = 0 And Timer - StartTime < 10
        ' Wait for Edge to open or until 10 seconds have passed
    Loop

    If Edge.Windows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Doc As Object
        Set Doc = Edge.Windows(Edge.Windows.Count - 1).Document

        Dim TBLs As Object
        Set TBLs = Doc.getElementsByTagName("Table")

        MsgBox TBLs.Length
    Else
        MsgBox "Edge did not open within 10 seconds."
    End If
End Sub
```

The instruction
`Set TBLs = Doc.getElementsByTagName("Table")`
fails...

If I could obtain such number, then I could create an automatic routine to generate sheets with the right data query, importing the desired table (and only it) in Excel

Any suggestion?
Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that approach to automating Edge, but it doesn't work at all.  You need to use something like Selenium to automate Edge.

Comment: I asked to Bing AI... :D I know might not be the best way, but I was really desparate!
However, Selenium is not good for me... As far as I undesrtand it has to be installed on client computer if I want my excel file to work properly... 
Becasue the idea is to distribute the file, so I can't ask to installa Selenium too...

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70619305/11318818) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72220815/11318818) (neither tested by me) as alternatives to Selenium